# grep regex/globbing behavior on bash

Tags: regex, linux, grep, glob

I'm wondering how does +* gets interpreted here to result in this output. AFAIK grep should be using BRE regex here and if that happens it shd result in invalid target for quantifier sort of problem.

If * is getting globbed then how does + fit into the picture here. B,cos if I remove + then it doesn't work.

```
ec2-user@ip-10-181-1-124:~> ls -lrt | grep -i libncurses+*
-rw-r--r-- 1 ec2-user users          0 Oct 14 20:09 libncurses5-6.1-lp152.7.67.x86_64
-rw-r--r-- 1 ec2-user users          0 Oct 14 20:10 libncurses55-6.1-lp152.7.67.x86_64
-rw-r--r-- 1 ec2-user users          0 Oct 14 20:10 libncurses6-6.1-lp152.7.67.x86_64
-rw-r--r-- 1 ec2-user users          0 Oct 14 20:10 libncurses66-6.1-lp152.7.67.x86_64
```

More test commands

```
ec2-user@ip-10-181-1-124:~> ls -lrt | grep -i libncurses
-rw-r--r-- 1 ec2-user users          0 Oct 14 20:09 libncurses5-6.1-lp152.7.67.x86_64
-rw-r--r-- 1 ec2-user users          0 Oct 14 20:10 libncurses55-6.1-lp152.7.67.x86_64
-rw-r--r-- 1 ec2-user users          0 Oct 14 20:10 libncurses6-6.1-lp152.7.67.x86_64
-rw-r--r-- 1 ec2-user users          0 Oct 14 20:10 libncurses66-6.1-lp152.7.67.x86_64
ec2-user@ip-10-181-1-124:~> ls -lrt | grep -i libncurses+*
-rw-r--r-- 1 ec2-user users          0 Oct 14 20:09 libncurses5-6.1-lp152.7.67.x86_64
-rw-r--r-- 1 ec2-user users          0 Oct 14 20:10 libncurses55-6.1-lp152.7.67.x86_64
-rw-r--r-- 1 ec2-user users          0 Oct 14 20:10 libncurses6-6.1-lp152.7.67.x86_64
-rw-r--r-- 1 ec2-user users          0 Oct 14 20:10 libncurses66-6.1-lp152.7.67.x86_64
ec2-user@ip-10-181-1-124:~> ls -lrt | grep -i libncurses+
ec2-user@ip-10-181-1-124:~> ls -lrt | grep -i libncurses*
```

Comment: `+*` in BRE means a `+` zero or more times. `echo libncurses++++++ | grep -i libncurses+*`, `echo libncurses | grep -i libncurses+*`, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`+` has no special meaning in glob patterns. Since `libncurses+*` doesn't match any files, it's left unexpanded. So `grep -i libncurses+*` is equivalent to `grep -i 'libncurses+*'`.

In basic regular expressions, `+` also has no special meaning (in extended regular expressions it means 1 or more of the preceding pattern). So `+*` matches a sequence of zero or more `+` characters. Since none of the filenames have any `+` characters, this part of the regexp is irrelevant. You're just matching any filenames that contain `libncurses`.

```
ls -lrt | grep -i libncurses+
```

returns nothing because this is explicitly matching the `+` character, and none of the filenames have that character.

```
ls -lrt | grep -i libncurses*
```

is expanding the wildcard to all the filenames that begin with `libncurses`. So this is equivalent to

```
ls -lrt | grep -i libncurses5-6.1-lp152.7.67.x86_64 libncurses55-6.1-lp152.7.67.x86_64 libncurses6-6.1-lp152.7.67.x86_64 libncurses66-6.1-lp152.7.67.x86_64
```

This uses `libncurses5-6.1-lp152.7.67.x86_64`  as the regexp to match, and searches for it in the files `libncurses55-6.1-lp152.7.67.x86_64`, `libncurses6-6.1-lp152.7.67.x86_64`, and `libncurses66-6.1-lp152.7.67.x86_64`. The piped input is ignored when `grep` gets filename arguments.

Since none of those files contain any lines that match the regexp, nothing is printed.